# Problem with extracting data from AS400 using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ibm-midrange, business-intelligence

I am writing an SQL request to export data from AS400 using different relations.
I want to write it like that to reduce the time and increase the performance of my ETL (I have at least 29 million row to use it in my ETL).

SQL:

```
SELECT  A.x1, A.x2, A.x3, A.x4, A.x5,
        (SELECT B.y1, B.y2, B.y3, C.w1 as w 
        FROM TEST1 AS B inner join TEST2 AS C ON ((C.w2=B.y4) and (C.w3=B.y5)) 
        where (B.y6 = 2)),
        E.q1

FROM TEST3 AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TEST1 AS B ON (A.x6 = B.y7)
LEFT OUTER JOIN TEST4 AS E ON ((A.x6 = E.q2) AND (A.x7 = E.q3))
```

I really need help for this error

I got this exception:

> TITRE : Microsoft Visual Studio
>   Exception de HRESULT : 0xC0202009
>   Erreur sur Traitement [Source [2]] : Code d'erreur SSIS DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. Une erreur OLE DB s'est produite. Code d'erreur : 0x80004005.
>   Un enregistrement OLE DB est disponible. Source : « IBMDA400 Command » Hresult : 0x80004005 Description : « SQL0412 : Sous-requête non admise, car plus d'une colonne résultat
>   Cause . . . . . : La sous-requête d'un prédicat doit avoir uniquement une colonne résultat correspondante lorsque l'autre opérande du prédicat est une expression simple.  En effet, la sous-requête peut extraire zéro, une ou plusieurs valeurs constituant une liste mais apparaissant dans une seule colonne résultat. Que faire . . . : Modifiez le nombre d'éléments renvoyés par la sous-requête pour qu'il n'y ait qu'une seule colonne résultat ou remplacez l'autre opérande du prédicat pour obtenir une liste d'expressions. ».

Comment: As per the error message your subquery `SELECT B.y1, B.y2, B.y3, C.w1 as w ...` has more than one column. If you really want all of those columns you could make the subquery an outer apply and then include its columns in your main select.

Comment: the problem is persisting.

Comment: I'm confused.  Does SQL Server run on "ibm-midrange" computers?  I think your tags are wrong.

Comment: yes, checked. I found a solution but it's not the best one : 
  (SELECT B.y1,  
  FROM TEST1 AS B inner join TEST2 AS C ON ((C.w2=B.y4) and (C.w3=B.y5)) 
  where (B.y6 = 2)),
  (SELECT B.y2
  FROM TEST1 AS B inner join TEST2 AS C ON ((C.w2=B.y4) and (C.w3=B.y5)) 
  where (B.y6 = 2)),
  (SELECT B.y3
  FROM TEST1 AS B inner join TEST2 AS C ON ((C.w2=B.y4) and (C.w3=B.y5)) 
  where (B.y6 = 2)),
  (SELECT C.w1 as w 
  FROM TEST1 AS B inner join TEST2 AS C ON ((C.w2=B.y4) and (C.w3=B.y5)) 
  where (B.y6 = 2)),

Comment: Your subquery (if it worked) is not correlated to any of the outer tables. This seems to be a bigger problem. And understand that you need to use syntax that DB2 understands, not TSQL syntax. Seems to me you need to make your subquery a derived table and join it to your main query. I suggest you develop your query using DB2 tools to get the query correct. Then use that query in your SSIS logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your error is that the subquery is returning more than one column. AlwaysLearning already said that.

But the next issue is going to be that your subquery is returning multiple rows.

Unless

```
SELECT B.y1, B.y2, B.y3, C.w1 as w 
FROM TEST1 AS B inner join TEST2 AS C ON ((C.w2=B.y4) and (C.w3=B.y5)) 
where (B.y6 = 2)
```

only returns a single row. Notice that the subquery has no conditions that correlate to the outer select. Using the alias B in the subquery does not correlate it to the outer select because it is redefined in the inner select at `FROM TEST1 AS B`. This makes the alias local to the subquery, and hides the use of B in the outer select from the subquery. If that is not what you intended, and even if it was, you should always follow a simple rule in SQL, do not re-use alises.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "table expression" to join the extra data instead of a "scalar subquery".

Scalar subqueries are limited to one row (yours may return multiple rows) and one column (yours is clearly trying to return more than one column).

For example, you can do:

```
SELECT  A.x1, A.x2, A.x3, A.x4, A.x5,
        f.y1, f.y2, f.y3, f.w,
        E.q1
FROM TEST3 AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TEST1 AS B ON (A.x6 = B.y7)
LEFT OUTER JOIN TEST4 AS E ON ((A.x6 = E.q2) AND (A.x7 = E.q3))
left join (
  SELECT B.y1, B.y2, B.y3, C.w1 as w 
  FROM TEST1 AS B -- you should avoid reusing the same alias B, but OK
  inner join TEST2 AS C ON ((C.w2=B.y4) and (C.w3=B.y5)) 
  where (B.y6 = 2)
) f on 1 = 1 -- what's the join condition? I assume you want all rows to match
```

**EDIT TO SPEED UP THE QUERY**

You are selecting all the rows from table `A`; that's bound to be slow. Nevertheless, since your joins are equi-joins they can greatly benefit from indexes; the following indexes could make your query faster:

```
create index ix1 on TEST1 (y7, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5);

create index ix2 on TEST1 (y6, y1, y2, y3);

create index ix3 on TEST4 (q2, q3, q1);

create index ix4 on TEST2 (w2, w3, w1);
```

Comment: i have already tried this solution and it works fine. But the main problem that it takes a long period . I want to reduce the time that takes this querry to extract data .That's why i am trying to avoid joins and write it like subquerry.

Comment: @houssemeddineayari You are selecting all the rows from table `A`; that's bound to be slow. The indexes I added can greatly speed up your query, unless your are selecting too many rows. Actually, how many rows does your query select?